# How to translate "Vamo' a to'"?

Tags: letras, letras-de-canciones

How would you translate into English the phrase

> "vamo'a to'" ?

It is taken from song lyrics and the following line is :

> "no hay control" (there is no control?).

I think the first part is just short for **vamos a** (let's go...) but I cannot figure out what **to'** is abbreviating.

Answer (score 3):

In this case is "vamos a todo" you can be translated as :

> "let's go to do everything".

"Vamo'a to'" is a vulgar way of saying :

> "Vamos a todo", or "vamos a hacer lo que sea" or "vamos a hacer de todo".

Answer (score 2):

That "to" is an informal abbreviation for "todo", where the D is pronnounced as mute ("TO-o")

So it would be "vamos a todo" (let's go [and do] everything).

Answer (score 1):

That is like "let's do this!". We use that phrase in my country more than often, is a common expression in the caribbiean.